# can i show image after select option?

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image]

i want this link in my localhost db display to image i try alot way but had errors anyway to show image after select option > recommended or advice me please Thank you

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["co"].'">'.$row["co"].'</option>';
            
        }
```

Java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#city').lwMultiSelect();
    $('.action').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            var query = $(this).val();
            var result = '';
            if(action == 'book')
            {
                result = 'nk';
            }else
            {
                result ='ao';
            }

            if(action == 'ao')
            { 
                result='co';
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                url:'fetch.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action, query:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#'+result).html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
    
});
```

Comment: So...what does fetch.php do? Is it the same as the PHP code above? Because that just outputs some options, not image tags. Where is your attempt to output images? What goes wrong when you try, exactly? The question is unclear

Comment: how do you built your dropdown, specifically, the dropdown that has image list? please provide the snippet codes for it.

Comment: fetch.php do in first column if i not pick first column then second column'll not show main point is 3 and 4 column is picture column 1 and 2 is name and type after pick show image i try to put <option value=" <img src='.$row["co"].'" /> >'.$row["co"].'</option> seem doesn't work

Comment: i want they'll show like this https://imgur.com/a/2seR7NW , have 4 so confused

Comment: You can't put an image inside a drop-down option. HTML doesn't support that. If you want to show it outside the drop-down, then you need to write code which puts the image tag outside the drop-down, right now it's inside it

Comment: Could you show code example or keyword to search info ? @ariefbayu here https://jsfiddle.net/upmomo/ub26w7jc/1/

Comment: What do you mean? Just write the image tag outside the drop-down, that's all there is to it

Comment: The way that select elements and their options are formatted is up to each browser. You can’t format them the normal way by e.g. adding a pseudo element to contain your image. Instead you will have to implement a substitute. For example an unordered list with each li element formatted as you want.